# MATLAB - Only plot a spherical section of data set which is cubic

Tags: matlab, plot, interpolation

I have a physics model that simulates a few things in a radius of 5000 km around an object in spherical coordinates. I found no way to interpolate spherical coordinates in MATLAB so I changed them to Cartesian with sph2cart function. Then I used scatteredinterpolant function with a 10000 by 10000 by 10000 km meshgrid to interpolate the data. I want to plot this data but only the sphere of a radius 5000 km. Is there a nice way to plot a certain specified volume of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to delete part of your data "spherically" you can do

being x,y,z your geometric data and v the values:

```
level=5000; %km (or whatever value it is in your data)
V(sqrt(X.^2+Y.^+Z.^2)>level)=0;

%or depending in the plotting functions.

V(sqrt(X.^2+Y.^+Z.^2)>level)=NaN; 

% plot things
```

Comment: No the problem is that scatteredinterpolant function extrapolates everything outside the sphere and it is very inaccurate that is why I dont want it to show on the plots. See the next two links for plots I have now

https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZPAa
https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZPAN

Comment: I had the set value to zero option already in my code but when you want to plot in log scales you get errors but I never thought about NaN ! thank you very much :D

Comment: @Terranees btw, fantastic plots you have there. That really looks like science

Comment: FYI - Phobos (Martian Moon) is positioned in the center and is hit by solar wind particles. Because of these solar wind particles it loses particles from the surface. These lost particles are effected by forces like gravity and followed when they leave and that is what is visualized in the figure :) btw made a nice plot on bit higher resolution and how it looks like now, thanks again :D https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/ZPPH